# How to readjust the column header text in Primeface's table when using hidden search field?

Tags: html, css, primefaces

In developing a webpage, I'm adjusting a Primeface table with a search field at the top. The search field is supposed to work searching for the content of almost all columns in accordance to what the user types. The following is an image of the table now:

[image: Table now]

In order for the top field to work as intended, it seems there is a need to activate each desired column's search system (better understanding can be seen in [Primeface's own show case page](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml)). Those fields, though, are visually undesired and so have been hidden in the .css file with the code

```
.filter_box{
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
opacity: 0 !important;    
}
```

As a result, the search field isn't showing anymore, but the space where it lies continues leading to a design problem (see image above: the red square at the left points out the space where the hidden space field is and the arrow at the right points out the desired design).

As a newbie in web developing, my question is: how can I use the search system, not show it and not leave such design flaws behind? Is it possible to use my search field at the top fully without using Primeface's search system? (I tried simply erasing that part in the column's configuration, but it didn't work since the search field at the top stop showing the results)

As complement, here is my code now:

```
<ui:composition template="/logged_template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="hidden_misc">
                <h:inputHidden value="#{equipMiscBean.setList(usuariosBeanCrt.usuario.nivelAcesso, usuariosBeanCrt.usuario.empresas)}" />
            </h:form>
            <h:form id="misc">
                <p:panel styleClass="tabela_view" visible="#{dash_menu.get_menu_access(usuariosBeanCrt.usuario,'4')}" >
                    <p:dataTable 
                        id="equip_table" 
                        value="#{equipMiscBean.list_equip}" 
                        widgetVar="itensTable"
                        var="item"
                        emptyMessage="Itens não encontrados"
                        filteredValue="#{equipMiscBean.list_equip_filtered}" >

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:outputPanel>
                                <h:outputText value="Busca: " />
                                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                                             onkeyup="PF('itensTable').filter()" 
                                             style="min-width: 200px" 
                                             placeholder="Entre com a palavra chave"/>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>                        

                        <!--Column Equipamento-->
                        <p:column 
                            headerText="Equipamento" 
                            filterBy="#{item.nome}"
                            filterMatchMode="contains"
                            filterable="true" >
                            <f:facet name="filter">
                                <p:inputText 
                                    onchange="PF('itensTable').filter()" 
                                    disabled="true"
                                    class="filter_box"
                                    />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.nome}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        ...

                        <!--Column Details-->
                        <p:column 
                            headerText="Detalhes"
                            style="width: 80px; text-align: center;"  >
                            <h:outputFormat class="ui-button" value="#{item.linkTable}" escape="false" />                            
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>    
                </p:panel>    
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. This was done by adding `rendered="false"` to the search field facet's specification.

```
<f:facet name="filter">
    <p:inputText 
        onchange="PF('itensTable').filter()" 
        disabled="true"
        rendered="false"
        />
</f:facet>
```

With that done, the .css change with `filter_box` is no longer required and the search system works correctly.

Comment: But you need to do this for each unwanted filter. Creating better CSS (like something with `display:none` would have worked too. Just learn the basics of css,.

Comment: @Kukeltje indeed, but that way I'ld have to add `class="css_name_here"` in each filter facet, which means the work is even bigger (same one line per facet plus editing/creating the .css). For me it would have been better simply because the .css and the css call line was already written, which is not the case anymore ^.^

Comment: No. If you need it for each column, but a class on the datatable and create a more specific selector... Plus that, by choosing a right class name (I would have used 'hide_filters' instead of 'filter_box') it is more clear what happens